# Varnish 4: High cache-hit but high backend traffic

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-4

When running Varnish 4.0.3 and looking at varnishstat, it reports a cache-hit ratio of about 0.9 - 0.95 which I interpret as a 90-95% cache-hit ratio (incorrect?). I have a very low hit-pass count, so I cannot see that there is a lot of traffic that is not cacheable. The part that bothers me is that the backend servers are working quite a bit despite this. When I look at iftop I see that the server (which isn't running any other applications) is transmitting at about 19Mbit (includes answers to the clients and request headers to backend servers) and receiving about 14Mbit from the backend servers.

I can add that I also have a small grace period in my cache and I see that about 1-2 requests per second get counted as hits but still make a request to the backend, but that is an insignificant number of requests.

I must be missing something that should be obvious. But what?

Edit:

```
    MAIN.uptime              70613         1.00 Child process uptime
    MAIN.sess_conn           43313         0.61 Sessions accepted
    MAIN.sess_drop               0         0.00 Sessions dropped
    MAIN.sess_fail               0         0.00 Session accept failures
    MAIN.sess_pipe_overflow            0         0.00 Session pipe overflow
    MAIN.client_req_400                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 400 errors
    MAIN.client_req_411                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 411 errors
    MAIN.client_req_413                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 413 errors
    MAIN.client_req_417                0         0.00 Client requests received, subject to 417 errors
    MAIN.client_req              6438096        91.17 Good client requests received
    MAIN.cache_hit               5231719        74.09 Cache hits
    MAIN.cache_hitpass            149819         2.12 Cache hits for pass
    MAIN.cache_miss               619678         8.78 Cache misses
    MAIN.backend_conn              19491         0.28 Backend conn. success
    MAIN.backend_unhealthy             0         0.00 Backend conn. not attempted
    MAIN.backend_busy                  0         0.00 Backend conn. too many
    MAIN.backend_fail                  0         0.00 Backend conn. failures
    MAIN.backend_reuse           1279156        18.12 Backend conn. reuses
    MAIN.backend_toolate            5046         0.07 Backend conn. was closed
    MAIN.backend_recycle         1284221        18.19 Backend conn. recycles
    MAIN.backend_retry                 5         0.00 Backend conn. retry
    MAIN.fetch_head                    7         0.00 Fetch no body (HEAD)
    MAIN.fetch_length             166348         2.36 Fetch with Length
    MAIN.fetch_chunked            861097        12.19 Fetch chunked
    MAIN.fetch_eof                     0         0.00 Fetch EOF
    MAIN.fetch_bad                     0         0.00 Fetch bad T-E
    MAIN.fetch_close                 862         0.01 Fetch wanted close
    MAIN.fetch_oldhttp                 0         0.00 Fetch pre HTTP/1.1 closed
    MAIN.fetch_zero               192834         2.73 Fetch zero len body
    MAIN.fetch_1xx                     0         0.00 Fetch no body (1xx)
    MAIN.fetch_204                     0         0.00 Fetch no body (204)
    MAIN.fetch_304                 77295         1.09 Fetch no body (304)
    MAIN.fetch_failed                  0         0.00 Fetch failed (all causes)
    MAIN.fetch_no_thread               0         0.00 Fetch failed (no thread)
    MAIN.pools                         2          .   Number of thread pools
    MAIN.threads                     400          .   Total number of threads
    MAIN.threads_limited               0         0.00 Threads hit max
    MAIN.threads_created             400         0.01 Threads created
    MAIN.threads_destroyed             0         0.00 Threads destroyed
    MAIN.threads_failed                0         0.00 Thread creation failed
    MAIN.thread_queue_len              0          .   Length of session queue
    MAIN.busy_sleep                   22         0.00 Number of requests sent to sleep on busy objhdr
    MAIN.busy_wakeup                  22         0.00 Number of requests woken after sleep on busy objhdr
    MAIN.sess_queued                   0         0.00 Sessions queued for thread
    MAIN.sess_dropped                  0         0.00 Sessions dropped for thread
    MAIN.n_object                  61732          .   object structs made
    MAIN.n_vampireobject               0          .   unresurrected objects
    MAIN.n_objectcore              61791          .   objectcore structs made
    MAIN.n_objecthead              59996          .   objecthead structs made
    MAIN.n_waitinglist               100          .   waitinglist structs made
    MAIN.n_backend                     8          .   Number of backends
    MAIN.n_expired                412530          .   Number of expired objects
    MAIN.n_lru_nuked                   0          .   Number of LRU nuked objects
    MAIN.n_lru_moved             1938371          .   Number of LRU moved objects
    MAIN.losthdr                       0         0.00 HTTP header overflows
    MAIN.s_sess                    43313         0.61 Total sessions seen
    MAIN.s_req                   6438096        91.17 Total requests seen
    MAIN.s_pipe                      192         0.00 Total pipe sessions seen
    MAIN.s_pass                   586507         8.31 Total pass-ed requests seen
    MAIN.s_fetch                 1206185        17.08 Total backend fetches initiated
    MAIN.s_synth                       0         0.00 Total synthethic responses made
    MAIN.s_req_hdrbytes       4609529442     65278.77 Request header bytes
    MAIN.s_req_bodybytes          615275         8.71 Request body bytes
    MAIN.s_resp_hdrbytes      2888897421     40911.69 Response header bytes
    MAIN.s_resp_bodybytes    95537815896   1352977.72 Response body bytes
    MAIN.s_pipe_hdrbytes           57835         0.82 Pipe request header bytes
    MAIN.s_pipe_in                 45698         0.65 Piped bytes from client
    MAIN.s_pipe_out              1305816        18.49 Piped bytes to client
    MAIN.sess_closed               24747         0.35 Session Closed
    MAIN.sess_pipeline                 0         0.00 Session Pipeline
    MAIN.sess_readahead                0         0.00 Session Read Ahead
    MAIN.sess_herd                813362        11.52 Session herd
    MAIN.shm_records           512140676      7252.78 SHM records
    MAIN.shm_writes             18119050       256.60 SHM writes
    MAIN.shm_flushes              788498        11.17 SHM flushes due to overflow
    MAIN.shm_cont                  89983         1.27 SHM MTX contention
    MAIN.shm_cycles                  277         0.00 SHM cycles through buffer
    MAIN.sms_nreq                      0         0.00 SMS allocator requests
    MAIN.sms_nobj                      0          .   SMS outstanding allocations
    MAIN.sms_nbytes                    0          .   SMS outstanding bytes
    MAIN.sms_balloc                    0          .   SMS bytes allocated
    MAIN.sms_bfree                     0          .   SMS bytes freed
    MAIN.backend_req             1298448        18.39 Backend requests made
    MAIN.n_vcl                         1         0.00 Number of loaded VCLs in total
    MAIN.n_vcl_avail                   1         0.00 Number of VCLs available
    MAIN.n_vcl_discard                 0         0.00 Number of discarded VCLs
    MAIN.bans                          1          .   Count of bans
    MAIN.bans_completed                1          .   Number of bans marked 'completed'
    MAIN.bans_obj                      0          .   Number of bans using obj.*
    MAIN.bans_req                      0          .   Number of bans using req.*
    MAIN.bans_added                    1         0.00 Bans added
    MAIN.bans_deleted                  0         0.00 Bans deleted
    MAIN.bans_tested                   0         0.00 Bans tested against objects (lookup)
    MAIN.bans_obj_killed               0         0.00 Objects killed by bans (lookup)
    MAIN.bans_lurker_tested            0         0.00 Bans tested against objects (lurker)
    MAIN.bans_tests_tested             0         0.00 Ban tests tested against objects (lookup)
    MAIN.bans_lurker_tests_tested            0         0.00 Ban tests tested against objects (lurker)
    MAIN.bans_lurker_obj_killed              0         0.00 Objects killed by bans (lurker)
    MAIN.bans_dups                           0         0.00 Bans superseded by other bans
    MAIN.bans_lurker_contention              0         0.00 Lurker gave way for lookup
    MAIN.bans_persisted_bytes               13          .   Bytes used by the persisted ban lists
    MAIN.bans_persisted_fragmentation            0          .   Extra bytes in persisted ban lists due to fragmentation
    MAIN.n_purges                                0          .   Number of purge operations executed
    MAIN.n_obj_purged                            0          .   Number of purged objects
    MAIN.exp_mailed                         949607        13.45 Number of objects mailed to expiry thread
    MAIN.exp_received                       949607        13.45 Number of objects received by expiry thread
    MAIN.hcb_nolock                        6001341        84.99 HCB Lookups without lock
    MAIN.hcb_lock                           447556         6.34 HCB Lookups with lock
    MAIN.hcb_insert                         447556         6.34 HCB Inserts
    MAIN.esi_errors                              0         0.00 ESI parse errors (unlock)
    MAIN.esi_warnings                            0         0.00 ESI parse warnings (unlock)
    MAIN.vmods                                   2          .   Loaded VMODs
    MAIN.n_gzip                             558747         7.91 Gzip operations
    MAIN.n_gunzip                            22866         0.32 Gunzip operations
    MAIN.vsm_free                           970832          .   Free VSM space
    MAIN.vsm_used                         83963776          .   Used VSM space
    MAIN.vsm_cooling                             0          .   Cooling VSM space
    MAIN.vsm_overflow                            0          .   Overflow VSM space
    MAIN.vsm_overflowed                          0         0.00 Overflowed VSM space
    MGT.uptime                               70613         1.00 Management process uptime
    MGT.child_start                              1         0.00 Child process started
    MGT.child_exit                               0         0.00 Child process normal exit
    MGT.child_stop                               0         0.00 Child process unexpected exit
    MGT.child_died                               0         0.00 Child process died (signal)
    MGT.child_dump                               0         0.00 Child process core dumped
    MGT.child_panic                              0         0.00 Child process panic
    MEMPOOL.vbc.live                            24          .   In use
    MEMPOOL.vbc.pool                            10          .   In Pool
    MEMPOOL.vbc.sz_wanted                       88          .   Size requested
    MEMPOOL.vbc.sz_needed                      120          .   Size allocated
    MEMPOOL.vbc.allocs                       19491         0.28 Allocations
    MEMPOOL.vbc.frees                        19467         0.28 Frees
    MEMPOOL.vbc.recycle                      19436         0.28 Recycled from pool
    MEMPOOL.vbc.timeout                      11998         0.17 Timed out from pool
    MEMPOOL.vbc.toosmall                         0         0.00 Too small to recycle
    MEMPOOL.vbc.surplus                          0         0.00 Too many for pool
    MEMPOOL.vbc.randry                          55         0.00 Pool ran dry
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.live                         6          .   In use
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.pool                         9          .   In Pool
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.sz_wanted                65536          .   Size requested
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.sz_needed                65568          .   Size allocated
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.allocs                 1298643        18.39 Allocations
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.frees                  1298637        18.39 Frees
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.recycle                1298436        18.39 Recycled from pool
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.timeout                  41750         0.59 Timed out from pool
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.toosmall                     0         0.00 Too small to recycle
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.surplus                      0         0.00 Too many for pool
    MEMPOOL.busyobj.randry                     207         0.00 Pool ran dry
    MEMPOOL.req0.live                            4          .   In use
    MEMPOOL.req0.pool                            9          .   In Pool
    MEMPOOL.req0.sz_wanted                   65536          .   Size requested
    MEMPOOL.req0.sz_needed                   65568          .   Size allocated
    MEMPOOL.req0.allocs                     423162         5.99 Allocations
    MEMPOOL.req0.frees                      423158         5.99 Frees
    MEMPOOL.req0.recycle                    423143         5.99 Recycled from pool
    MEMPOOL.req0.timeout                     36313         0.51 Timed out from pool
    MEMPOOL.req0.toosmall                        0         0.00 Too small to recycle
    MEMPOOL.req0.surplus                         0         0.00 Too many for pool
    MEMPOOL.req0.randry                         19         0.00 Pool ran dry
    MEMPOOL.sess0.live                           4          .   In use
    MEMPOOL.sess0.pool                           9          .   In Pool
    MEMPOOL.sess0.sz_wanted                    384          .   Size requested
    MEMPOOL.sess0.sz_needed                    416          .   Size allocated
    MEMPOOL.sess0.allocs                     21655         0.31 Allocations
    MEMPOOL.sess0.frees                      21651         0.31 Frees
    MEMPOOL.sess0.recycle                    21642         0.31 Recycled from pool
    MEMPOOL.sess0.timeout                    10076         0.14 Timed out from pool
    MEMPOOL.sess0.toosmall                       0         0.00 Too small to recycle
    MEMPOOL.sess0.surplus                        0         0.00 Too many for pool
    MEMPOOL.sess0.randry                        13         0.00 Pool ran dry
    MEMPOOL.req1.live                            6          .   In use
    MEMPOOL.req1.pool                            9          .   In Pool
    MEMPOOL.req1.sz_wanted                   65536          .   Size requested
    MEMPOOL.req1.sz_needed                   65568          .   Size allocated
    MEMPOOL.req1.allocs                     418423         5.93 Allocations
    MEMPOOL.req1.frees                      418417         5.93 Frees
    MEMPOOL.req1.recycle                    418406         5.93 Recycled from pool
    MEMPOOL.req1.timeout                     35924         0.51 Timed out from pool
    MEMPOOL.req1.toosmall                        0         0.00 Too small to recycle
    MEMPOOL.req1.surplus                         0         0.00 Too many for pool
    MEMPOOL.req1.randry                         17         0.00 Pool ran dry
    MEMPOOL.sess1.live                           6          .   In use
    MEMPOOL.sess1.pool                          10          .   In Pool
    MEMPOOL.sess1.sz_wanted                    384          .   Size requested
    MEMPOOL.sess1.sz_needed                    416          .   Size allocated
    MEMPOOL.sess1.allocs                     21659         0.31 Allocations
    MEMPOOL.sess1.frees                      21653         0.31 Frees
    MEMPOOL.sess1.recycle                    21645         0.31 Recycled from pool
    MEMPOOL.sess1.timeout                    10040         0.14 Timed out from pool
    MEMPOOL.sess1.toosmall                       0         0.00 Too small to recycle
    MEMPOOL.sess1.surplus                        0         0.00 Too many for pool
    MEMPOOL.sess1.randry                        14         0.00 Pool ran dry
    SMA.s0.c_req                           1349644        19.11 Allocator requests
    SMA.s0.c_fail                                0         0.00 Allocator failures
    SMA.s0.c_bytes                     22210720975    314541.53 Bytes allocated
    SMA.s0.c_freed                     19148751042    271178.83 Bytes freed
    SMA.s0.g_alloc                          105992          .   Allocations outstanding
    SMA.s0.g_bytes                      3061969933          .   Bytes outstanding
    SMA.s0.g_space                      2306739187          .   Bytes available
    SMA.Transient.c_req                    1343403        19.02 Allocator requests
    SMA.Transient.c_fail                         0         0.00 Allocator failures
    SMA.Transient.c_bytes              24207322266    342816.79 Bytes allocated
    SMA.Transient.c_freed              24201619786    342736.04 Bytes freed
    SMA.Transient.g_alloc                     7499          .   Allocations outstanding
    SMA.Transient.g_bytes                  5702480          .   Bytes outstanding
    SMA.Transient.g_space                        0          .   Bytes available
    VBE.backend1([IP]).vcls            1          .   VCL references
    VBE.backend1([IP]).happy 18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
    VBE.backend1([IP]).bereq_hdrbytes    173320400      2454.51 Request header bytes
    VBE.backend1([IP]).bereq_bodybytes       238971         3.38 Request body bytes
    VBE.backend1([IP]).beresp_hdrbytes    124704577      1766.03 Response header bytes
    VBE.backend1([IP]).beresp_bodybytes  19209840560    272043.97 Response body bytes
    VBE.backend1([IP]).pipe_hdrbytes           14288         0.20 Pipe request header bytes
    VBE.backend1([IP]).pipe_out                 8069         0.11 Piped bytes to backend
    VBE.backend1([IP]).pipe_in                335893         4.76 Piped bytes from backend
    VBE.backend2([IP]).vcls                      1          .   VCL references
    VBE.backend2([IP]).happy          18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
    VBE.backend2([IP]).bereq_hdrbytes    173379423      2455.35 Request header bytes
    VBE.backend2([IP]).bereq_bodybytes        76962         1.09 Request body bytes
    VBE.backend2([IP]).beresp_hdrbytes    124652416      1765.29 Response header bytes
    VBE.backend2([IP]).beresp_bodybytes  18690565655    264690.15 Response body bytes
    VBE.backend2([IP]).pipe_hdrbytes           14629         0.21 Pipe request header bytes
    VBE.backend2([IP]).pipe_out                 8558         0.12 Piped bytes to backend
    VBE.backend2([IP]).pipe_in                284168         4.02 Piped bytes from backend
    VBE.backend3([IP]).vcls                        1          .   VCL references
    VBE.backend3([IP]).happy            18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
    VBE.backend3([IP]).bereq_hdrbytes      173448768      2456.33 Request header bytes
    VBE.backend3([IP]).bereq_bodybytes         75294         1.07 Request body bytes
    VBE.backend3([IP]).beresp_hdrbytes     124641060      1765.13 Response header bytes
    VBE.backend3([IP]).beresp_bodybytes  18738758550    265372.64 Response body bytes
    VBE.backend3([IP]).pipe_hdrbytes           17940         0.25 Pipe request header bytes
    VBE.backend3([IP]).pipe_out                16704         0.24 Piped bytes to backend
    VBE.backend3([IP]).pipe_in                301836         4.27 Piped bytes from backend
    VBE.backend4([IP]).vcls                        1          .   VCL references
    VBE.backend4([IP]).happy            18446744073709551615          .   Happy health probes
    VBE.backend4([IP]).bereq_hdrbytes      173265357      2453.73 Request header bytes
    VBE.backend4([IP]).bereq_bodybytes        227023         3.22 Request body bytes
    VBE.backend4([IP]).beresp_hdrbytes     124724341      1766.31 Response header bytes
    VBE.backend4([IP]).beresp_bodybytes  18642562615    264010.35 Response body bytes
    VBE.backend4([IP]).pipe_hdrbytes           22537         0.32 Pipe request header bytes
    VBE.backend4([IP]).pipe_out                12367         0.18 Piped bytes to backend
    VBE.backend4([IP]).pipe_in                383919         5.44 Piped bytes from backend
    LCK.sma.creat                                                                              2         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.sma.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.sma.locks                                                                        5272603        74.67 Lock Operations
LCK.hcb.locks                                                                         837080        11.85 Lock Operations
    LCK.hcl.creat                                                                              0         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.hcl.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.hcl.locks                                                                              0         0.00 Lock Operations
    LCK.vcl.creat                                                                              1         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.vcl.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.vcl.locks                                                                        2604799        36.89 Lock Operations
    LCK.sess.creat                                                                         43306         0.61 Created locks
    LCK.sess.destroy                                                                       43304         0.61 Destroyed locks
    LCK.sess.locks                                                                          4765         0.07 Lock Operations
    LCK.wstat.creat                                                                            1         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.wstat.destroy                                                                          0         0.00 Destroyed locks
  LCK.wstat.locks                                                                      3421304        48.45 Lock Operations
    LCK.wq.locks                                                                         6449131        91.33 Lock Operations
    LCK.objhdr.creat                                                                      447638         6.34 Created locks
    LCK.objhdr.destroy                                                                    387644         5.49 Destroyed locks
    LCK.objhdr.locks                                                                    42615452       603.51 Lock Operations
    LCK.exp.creat                                                                              1         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.exp.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.exp.locks                                                                        4462106        63.19 Lock Operations
    LCK.lru.creat                                                                              2         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.lru.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.lru.locks                                                                        4259219        60.32 Lock Operations
    LCK.cli.creat                                                                              1         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.cli.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.cli.locks                                                                          23549         0.33 Lock Operations
    LCK.ban.creat                                                                              1         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.ban.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.ban.locks                                                                        1594008        22.57 Lock Operations
    LCK.vbp.creat                                                                              1         0.00 Created locks
    LCK.vbp.destroy                                                                            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
    LCK.vbp.locks                                                                         112922         1.60 Lock Operations
LCK.backend.locks                                                                    2626872        37.20 Lock Operations
    LCK.vcapace.creat                                                                          1         0.00 Created locks
```

*Had to remove some (uneventful parts) from the log due to message limit.

In this I calculated "other non-cacheable requests" by client_req - (cache_hit + cache_hitpass + cache_miss) = 436880. That along with cache_hitpass and cache misses (or just client_req-cache-hit) which are not cached brings the total to 586699, or about 18.7%. If they are heavy requests I suppose that could account for the traffic. But I'm a bit unconvinced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to look at the access log of one of the servers? Maybe you have requests coming in not through Varnish?

Also, I know that at least in Varnish 3, the cache hit rate is calculated from hits that **can** come from cache to begin with. For example, with a standard configuration, POST requests are not counted there.

The access log may give you some insight...

Comment: Since I am running iftop on the varnish server, I know that the traffic from the backend server is coming to the varnish server and not heading toward some other servers. I will however have to check the logs for POST requests. Is there a way to spot those kinds of requests in varnishstat?

Comment: According to the logs I get about 0.2 POST requests per second. (I get about 250 requests per second in total)

Comment: I don't know of a way to spot such requests in varnishstat... Did you try looking at the access log on one of the back-end servers?

Comment: "POST" was just an example... AFAIK any request that is passed instead of retrieved from the cache would not be counted in the hit rate (again, at least in Varnish 3... I have no experience with 4)